# PopUp Loading in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin

I am creating an app with Xamarin and I want to create a Loading Modal while I send and wait a response of a webservice. I was searching some examples and I found Modal Page and Rg.Plugins.PopUp but I still cannot do this works.

The problem with PopUp is that it always open after the response of webservice and not before and I can´t understant why it is happens.

How could I do this works ?

**PopUp Page**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pages:PopupPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
    xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
    x:Class="CooperativaApp.View.PopUpLoading"
    CloseWhenBackgroundIsClicked="False">
    <!--You can set an animation in the xaml file or in the csharp code behind-->
    <pages:PopupPage.Animation>
        <animations:ScaleAnimation 
            PositionIn="Center"
            PositionOut="Center"
            ScaleIn="1.2"
            ScaleOut="0.8"
            DurationIn="400"
            DurationOut="300"
            EasingIn="SinOut"
            EasingOut="SinIn"
            HasBackgroundAnimation="True"
            />
    </pages:PopupPage.Animation>
    <!--You can use any elements here which are extended from Xamarin.Forms.View-->
    <StackLayout 
        VerticalOptions="Center" 
        HorizontalOptions="Center" 
        Padding="20, 20, 20, 20"
        BackgroundColor="White">
        <ActivityIndicator             
            IsRunning="True"
            IsVisible="True"
            Color="Green"/>
    </StackLayout>
</pages:PopupPage>
```

**Searching on the WebService**

```
private void OnClickAcessar(object sender, EventArgs args){
            //open popup loading
            PopUpLoading loading = new PopUpLoading();                     
            PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(loading, true);

            //user object
            Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
            usuario.login = "admin";
            usuario.pswd = "admin";

            //webservice login
            UsuarioService service = new UsuarioService();
            service.doLogin(usuario);

            //close popup loading
            PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();
        }
```

Comment: Try awaiting your pushes/pops for your popup.

Comment: @Nick Are you suggesting to use `await` for example `await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(loading, true);` ?

Comment: Yeah and I'm not sure what Rg.Plugins would do if you try to pop a popup when one hasn't been shown yet, which may be why it's not getting dismissed.

Comment: @Nick I tried to use `await` but it throws an exception. Please, look at the picture https://i.imgur.com/wRVktaD.png

Comment: you need to set your method to async `private async void OnClickAcessar`

Comment: @Nick thanks a lot. It works very well.

Answer (score 2):

The best loader for me in xamarin is this : https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs

```
 void CallService ()
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading ("Loading ...", MaskType.Black));
    Task.Run (() => {
        //webservice login
        UsuarioService service = new UsuarioService();
        service.doLogin(usuario);
    }).ContinueWith (result => Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {

        UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading ();

        }
    })
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private async void OnClickAcessar(object sender, EventArgs args){

           //open popup loading with await
            PopUpLoading loading = new PopUpLoading();                     
            await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(loading, true);

            //user object
            Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
            usuario.login = "admin";
            usuario.pswd = "admin";

            //webservice login
            UsuarioService service = new UsuarioService();
            service.doLogin(usuario);

            //close popup loading with await
            await  PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();
            // or used
            // await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(loading, false);
        }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

While it can't be seen from your code, you are likely not executing the service with `Task.Run`. That way it runs on the UI thread and prevents UI from updating. There are many answers on this topic, I myself gave several of them which contain more detailed explanation.